# Three.js model file changed but rendered model is the same?

Tags: three.js

I'm using three.js to render a model that is localy stored in my system folder. In chrome after I render the first time the model files seems to be stored in cache because if i change the file and reload the page the there is no change in the rendered model. I cannot clear the cache due to other reasons . Kindly help me with this problem. Is there any way i can reload the models after the files are changed. Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your first issue, three.js would always cache the model files to reduce the time taken to load the files. To overcome this you can make use of the anti-cache trick, that is to append a random value to the end of the model file url like this.

```
     "http://localhost/models/model.json?" + Math.random()
```

Hope it helps!